# Using labels to automatically write reply and close issue/PR on Github

Tags: github, github-api, probot

I would like to know if there is an existing way (probably app) to automatically write a reply and close an issue on Github based on a tag.

For example, if I tag an issue with the label "upstream-something", I would like that it to write "your issue should be filled in something.com" and then close the issue.

Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use probot framework and check the issues event, from context object you will all the information regarding labels and then using same context object you can comment on the issue, please go to the below link to build a probot app
https://developer.github.com/apps/